# need to identify a perennial that has black arrowhead shape on leaves?

Tags: identification

I have a perennial plant that has dark brown arrowhead shape on green leaves, in the fall long tiny red seed heads. What is it?

Comment: A photograph would be really, really helpful, not to say essential - otherwise, how tall and wide does it grow?